# Is there any login REST-API for user in keycloak?

Tags: node.js, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

Is there any login REST-API for created users in keycloak?

I used API

```
{{root}}/realms/{{realm}}/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

but it gives only access token but I need full information of the user.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is user info API which provides information of currently logged in user:

Try this: (by passing the token obtained from url you mentioned : `{{root}}/realms/{{realm}}/protocol/openid-connect/token`)

`GET "{root}/auth/realms/yourRealmName/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo"`

A sample response from my setup:

```
{
    "sub": "d32be694-f438-44a5-95f2-7434ff37ca1e",
    "email_verified": false,
    "roles": [
        "Administrator"
    ],
    "groups": [
        "Administrator"
    ],
    "preferred_username": "administrator" 
}
```